# IP Address translated into distance from particular Zip Code

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, geolocation

What I would LOVE to do is be able to grab a users IP address and discern how many approximate miles it is from my fixed location. I realize through the use of services or databases that I'd be able to find the City and zip code but I'd like to also find out the approximate distance between the users ZIP and my ZIP.

I have seen a services and databases to get the Zip/City/Country from a users IP. I've also used some PHP classes to get the distance from one zip code to another. Hypothetically I could use the one database to get the zip and the other to compare the distance between the two zips but that seems very resource intensive (at least 2 queries plus processing).

I just want to show an advertisement for a museum exhibition if the user is within 100 or so miles (based on IP). If not I'm not going to show it because it seems like they'd be too far away.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Also, I do not want the browser to ask the user if I can use their geo-location in my application by using the new HTML5 stuff. I'd rather this all happen behind the scenes without the location based awareness (and user Opt-In) unless there's an overwhelming reason to use it.

I'd be open to any solutions but hoping to find one in the PHP/MYSQL/jQuery/Javascript realm.

Thanks

Comment: My IP address comes by DSL from my ISP, who is a 4-hour drive away. It's never right.

Comment: my isp is international, sometimes my ip lookup shows the wrong country.

Comment: You mean like ip-tracker.org? You could screen scrape that or see if there's an API for it

Comment: good luck with cellular users. their IP is invariably some NAT gateway which can be literally thousands of miles away from th phone's physical location. IPs are a very poor way to track location for a large swath of the IP space.

Comment: only about 6% of my traffic comes from mobile devices, I'm prepared to live with that. Though some of the other concerns about ISP IP lookups being hours away is a much bigger concern. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a service that my company uses called Zip Code Services.  It is located at https://www.zipcodeservices.com.  It does everything you've highlighted in your question.

1. You can get distance between 2 zip codes.
2. You can pass an IP address in and an integer for radius and it will give you all of the zipcodes in radius of that IP address.

We actually use Zip Code Services IP Address and Zip Code Services to display geo-located ads to our website viewers.

What's cool is it's all service-based (Rest/JSON, XML or SOAP - you take your pick) and it's pretty inexpensive, too -- it's like $15 a month.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like http://www.geoiptool.com/ or other similar service (even one of the Google APIs).

Then as it provides lat/long coords, just map the distance to your own using the following function. Be careful though - some lat/long coords for IP addresses are way off target and won't correlate for mobiles/cells at all. IP's don't roam well:

```
function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true)
{
        $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
        $lat1 *= $pi80;
        $lng1 *= $pi80;
        $lat2 *= $pi80;
        $lng2 *= $pi80;

        $r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km
        $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
        $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
        $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);
        $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
        $km = $r * $c;

        return ($miles ? ($km * 0.621371192) : $km);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems to solve for you, (1) getting the lat/lon of your users and (2) calculating the distance.  For (2), you want to use the haversine formula:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos(φ1).cos(φ2).sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!
```

Comment: Hadn't seen the Movable Type link before. Good resource!